# Defining many-to-many bidirectional relations more eloquently

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have implemented the relationship without Eloquent but I was wondering is there was a way to define this relationship in Eloquent so that my application can have more consistency.

```
table User
    -id
    -other user attributes

table friend_requests:
    -id
    -sender_id
    -reciever_id

table friends
    -id
    -first
    -second
```

The friendRequest relation has been easily implemented in the Eloquent but the problem lies in Friends.

If I do this in the User model class:

```
public function friends(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'friends','first','second');
}
```

This wouldn't work as you would have noticed. Let me explain with example:

```
Table: friends 
 id    |   first    | second  
 1     |   1        | 2  
 2     |   3        | 1
```

you see that `user_1` is friends with `user_2` as well as `user_3` as the relationship is bi-directional. But Eloquent will naturally return that `user_1` is friends with `user_2` only. After thinking for a while I tweaked the statement but made little progress'

```
public function friends(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'friends','first','second')
                ->orWhere('second',$this->id);
}
```

That is because now it selects both rows but the `User`s it returns are those whose `id` = `second` which means that in the second case it will return the user itself.

I implemented the relations with my own methods in `User` model class which use `DB::table('friends')->` to `addFriend(User $user)`, `removeFriend(user $user)` and returns list of `friends()`, but I'm disappointed that this isn't as eloquent as `Eloquent` relationships.

Perhaps some more experienced developers here would have come across this kind of problem and would have dealt better than I did. How do you propose I deal with this problem. Should I stick with my approach or is there a better way to deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more manageable way to implement bidirectional relations would be to create two entries for each confirmed friendship.

So a user would make a friend request to another user. When the second user confirms the friend request, two friendships are created.

### Example Controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\FriendRequest;
use App\Friendship;

class FriendshipController extends Controller
{
    public function friendRequest(Request $request)
    {
        $receiver_id = $request->input('receiver_id');

        $request->user()->friend_offers()->create([
            'receiver_id' => $receiver_id
        ]);
    }

    public function friendshipConfirmation(Request $request)
    {
        $friend_request_id = $request->input('friend_request_id');

        $friend_request = FriendRequest::find($friend_request_id);

        $friend_request->receiver->friendships()->create([
            'user_2_id' => $friend_request->sender->id
        ]);

        $friend_request->sender->friendships()->create([
            'user_2_id' => $friend_request->receiver->id
        ]);
    }
}
```

### Database Tables

(Note the proper spelling of `receiver` and plural `users` table)

```
table users
    - id
    - other user attributes

table friend_requests:
    - id
    - sender_id
    - receiver_id

table friendships
    - id
    - user_1_id
    - user_2_id
```

### User Model

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public $timestamps = true;

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];

    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Return friend requests from other users
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function friend_requests()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FriendRequest::class, 'receiver_id');
    }

    /**
     * Return friend requests sent to other users
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function friend_offers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FriendRequest::class, 'sender_id');
    }

    /**
     * Return friendships with other users
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function friendships()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Friendship::class, 'user_1_id');
    }
}
```

### FriendRequest Model

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class FriendRequest extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public $timestamps = true;

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];

    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'sender_id',
        'receiver_id'
    ];

    /**
     * Return the requesting user
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function sender()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'sender_id');
    }

    /**
     * Return the receiving user
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function receiver()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'receiver_id');
    }
}
```

### Friendship Model

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Friendship extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public $timestamps = true;

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];

    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_1_id',
        'user_2_id'
    ];

    /**
     * Return user_1
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function first()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_1_id');
    }

    /**
     * Return user_2
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function second()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_2_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort but do you think that having double entries for one relationship a good idea? I mean it is much cleaner than what I implemented, but I was hoping for more eloquent approach. I guess Eloquent does not promise to make every relationship eloquent.

Comment: Yes, I think it is a good idea because it minimizes complexity and possibility for confusion. There is usually more database and computing power available than there is developer perfection. This is straightforward for the developer.

Answer (score 0):

I got bidirectional relations working by union `morphToMany()` and `morphedByMany()` with a little workaround as described here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/50302

**Table Structure**

```
contacts
    id (uuid)
    props
    
contactables
    id
    contact_id
    contactable_type
    contactable_id
    type (type of relation (string/enum) e.g. "family", "work", "test")
```

**Method that returns the bidirectional relations of the model**

```php
// App\Models\Contact
public function relatedTestContacts(): MorphToMany
{
    $first = $this->morphToMany(Contact::class, 'contactable')
        ->withPivot('type')
        ->wherePivot('type', 'test');

    // Define selects as produced by the morphToMany() method above
    // This has to be done by hand, as long as the selects differ
    // ERROR: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
    $select = [
        $this->getTable() . '.*',
        // Pivot
        "contactables.contactable_id as pivot.contactable_id",
        "contactables.contact_id as pivot.contact_id",
        "contactables.contactables as pivot.contactables",
        // Additional Pivot Attributes
        "contactables.type as pivot.type",
    ];

    $second = $this->morphedByMany(Contact::class, 'contactable')
        ->withPivot('type')
        ->wherePivot('type', 'test')
        ->select($select);

    return $first->union($second)->beforeQuery(function (\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $builder) {
        // Avoid order by qualified column name in union select
        // SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1250 Table 'contacts' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in ORDER clause
        $builder->reorder('id');
    });
}
```