# Self referencing "ownerless" many_many relationships?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, foreign-keys

I have a many many relationship where I don't care **who** created the relationship, if the querying models ID is in **either side** of the relationship I need the other side.

--

Let's say I have this model

```
class Ingredient extends Model
{

    public function complements()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
                   self::class, 'ingredient_complements', 
                   'ingredient_id', 'complement_id'
               );
    }

}
```

And I've created a few different instances as below

```
$ing1 = new Ingredient();
$ing2 = new Ingredient();
$ing3 = new Ingredient();
$ing4 = new Ingredient();
$ing5 = new Ingredient();
$ing6 = new Ingredient();

$ing1->save(); //2,3,4,5,6...
```

Next I go through and relate a few of them

```
$ing1->complements()->attach($ing2);
$ing2->complements()->attach($ing3);
$ing3->complements()->attach($ing4);
$ing4->complements()->attach($ing6);
$ing5->complements()->attach($ing6);
$ing6->complements()->attach($ing1);
```

So now we have a pivot table that looks like

```
| ing_id | cmp_id |
| 1      | 2      |
| 2      | 3      |
| 3      | 4      |
| 4      | 5      |
| 5      | 6      |
| 6      | 1      |
```

So..
if I call `$ing1->complements` I'll get back ing2
if I call `$ing2->complements` I'll get back ing3

But..
if I call `$ing2->complements` I **won't** get back ing1
if I call `$ing3->complements` I **won't** get back ing2

I need to fix that.

I've got a second method that I'm using at the moment that I can call using `$ing3->complementaryIngredients;` which ends up executing something like

```
select * from `ingredients` 
inner join `ingredient_complements` on `ingredient_id` = '3' 
or `complement_id` = '3' and `ingredient_id` = `id` 
or `complement_id` = `id` where `id` <> '3'
```

Which works, but I don't feel this is something that I should have to break out of the ORM for?

```
public function getComplementaryIngredientsAttribute()
{
    return self::join('ingredient_complements', function(JoinClause $join){
        $join->where('ingredient_id', $this->id);
        $join->orWhere('complement_id', $this->id);
        $join->on('ingredient_id', '=', 'id');
        $join->orOn('complement_id', '=', 'id');
    })->where('id', '<>', $this->id)->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to define bi-directional relationship, so your model should have 1 more method which will define the opposite direction.

```
public function ingredients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
               self::class, 'ingredient_complements', 
               'complement_id', 'ingredient_id'
           );
}
```

Then you will get the other side of your relation in this way `$ing2->ingredients()` and it will return what you are looking for.

Another approach is to create model for your pivot table so you can query that model to get both sides of your relationship

Comment: The issue is there that I now need to manually join the results from both relations if I want the full result set. For now I've defined a manual join which seems to work (I'll add it to my question above) but I'm still not happy with it, I just find it hard to believe there's nothing like an "includeInverse()" function we can append onto our joins.

Comment: That is one of the reasons why I don't use Eloquent anymore and moved to doctrine. (Here)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39186350/defining-many-to-many-bidirectional-relations-more-eloquently] all eloquents solutions were already discussed and it's almost the same with what I wrote before.

Comment: [Check this out also](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/bi-directional-belongsto-relationship)

Comment: I'm curious, could you show me how in doctrine you would write this up?

Comment: Techically it's the same solution with some sugar around it. As for ODM, it's even doesn't create a new field for mappedBy annotated property